# jQuery Validation rules for tagsinput only triggered on submit event

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, bootstrap-tags-input

I use tags input and jquery validation for form,
but this kind of input only been validated on submit event. 
Any idea how to solve this? To let it be validated on change event?

Comment: You have not adequately described the problem or shown enough code to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Find answer from here: https://github.com/jquery-validation/jquery-validation/issues/997

```
$("#embed-form").validate().element(':input[name="upload_docs_file"]');
```

Comment: You're showing code to solve a coding problem that is not being shown in the question.  That makes no sense.  The question needs to be properly written and the answer needs to explain the solution.